# IDE specific SSL Handshake exception

Tags: java, ssl, configuration, ide, jdeveloper

I am getting an SSL Handshake exception when trying to run a code in JDeveloper. However, the exact same code is working fine in Netbeans IDE.

The error is;

> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I know the error comes most likely when the proper certificate is not present in the truststore. This is not the case here, as I can see the certificate being added as a trusted certificate after enabling the `javax.net.debug=ssl` logs.
Also, this cannot be a simple case of certificate not being available as the exact same code is working fine on Netbeans with the same truststore and java version.

The code is as follows;

```
package client;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;

public class Class1 {
    public Class1() {
        super();
    }
    private static final String resourceUrl = "My/url";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Response headers = null;
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\path\\to\\jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","passphrase");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","ssl");

        try {
            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            String auth = "username:password";
            byte[] authBytes = auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            String encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authBytes);
            String input = "JSON_input_payload";

            headers = client
                  .target(resourceUrl)
                  .request()
                  .header("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuth)                   
                  .post(Entity.json(input));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Response = " + headers);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?
Perhaps I need to check some IDE specific configuration files? Couldn't figure out what to look for in Jdev config files though, hence posting the question here.

Netbeans version is `8.2`

JDev versions I checked this on are `12.2.1.3.0` and `12.2.1.4.0`

OS is Windows 10.

The `java.version` is the same in bothe IDE's, i.e, `1.8.0_151`. I also tried running them in the version `1.8.0_221`, but got the same results.

Comment: [1] Does this help: [How to configure JDeveloper to trust an SSL certificate and fix PKIX path building failed when connecting to an Https URL?](https://cedricleruth.com/how-to-configure-jdeveloper-to-trust-an-ssl-certificate-and-fix-pkix-path-building-failed-when-connecting-to-an-https-url/) [2] I don't see why you have included a `netbeans` tag for this question if everything is fine in NetBeans.

Comment: [1] Did not help, but thanks! [2] Just added the tag since I did get the code working in netbeans. Thought it might help if there are any experienced people who know either of the two IDE's. But I get what you mean, let me remove the tag